# Chemfig: Bond line partly passing through atoms when shrinking

Tags: chemfig

How can I fix the bond to the top OCH3 group to not pass partly through the O?

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \schemestart
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-OH)-(*6(-=(-OGlc)-(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-(-(OC\ch{H3}))--))=\chemabove{O}{+}-))---(-[,,,2]HO)-)}
    + \ch{H2O}
    \arrow(aa--ab){<=>}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-OH)-(*6(-=(-OGlc)-(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-(-(OC\ch{H3}))--))(-[:105,1.5,,1]OH)-O-))---(-[,,,2]HO)-)}
    + \ch{H+}
    \arrow(@aa--ba){<=>}[-90]
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{*6(=(-OH)-(*6(=-(-OGlc)=(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-(-(OC\ch{H3}))--))-O-))-=-(=O)-)}
    + \ch{H3O+}
    \schemestop
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having `-` outside like this `-(OC\ch{H3})`, put it inside like so: `(-OC\ch{H3})`.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \schemestart
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-OH)-(*6(-=(-OGlc)-(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-((-OC\ch{H3}))--))=\chemabove{O}{+}-))---(-[,,,2]HO)-)}
    + \ch{H2O}
    \arrow(aa--ab){<=>}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-OH)-(*6(-=(-OGlc)-(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-((-OC\ch{H3}))--))(-[:105,1.5,,1]OH)-O-))---(-[,,,2]HO)-)}
    + \ch{H+}
    \arrow(@aa--ba){<=>}[-90]
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}
    \chemfig{*6(=(-OH)-(*6(=-(-OGlc)=(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-((-OC\ch{H3}))--))-O-))-=-(=O)-)}
    + \ch{H3O+}
    \schemestop
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good!! My compliments. It is the best answer for my opinion.

Comment: Thank you my dear sir!

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using Papeeria now I have several errors. Hence I have deleted some part of your code. My proposal - I thing that it is very easy but surely it is not the best answer -. You could put only a little space `\,`. See the image below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, norsk, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \chemfig{**6(-(-OH)-(*6(-=(-OGlc)-(-**6(--(-OC\ch{H3})-(-OH)-(-(\,OC\ch{H3}))--))=\chemabove{O}{+}-))---(-[,,,2]HO)-)}
    + \ch{H2O}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, bot does not look as good.
Some of the code you removed is the command to shrink the molecules to make the reaction aquation shown above fit the page. That is what is causing the line to go through the O.
The size-command is 
    \setchemfig{atom sep=1.22em}

Comment: @HenrikPaulsrudTangen I'm not a chemfig expert. I rarely use it. I'll tell you that I don't care about points or anything else. I hope it could be a solution for you. If you prefer I can remove my answer.

Comment: No, let it stay. It might be the best solution. Thank you very much, though!

Comment: @HenrikPaulsrudTangen I'm always available. I thank very much the kind and polite users. My greetings.